Different statements about the peripheral system as a complete knot invariant
I am somewhat confused about the different flavours in which the statement "the peripheral (group) system is a complete knot invariant" usually comes, and I believe not all of them have precisely the same strength, meaning that some might determine the knot up to orientation and/or mirror image. Here are some of them:

The peripheral system $(\pi_1 X_K, m,l)$,
The peripheral group system $(\pi_1 X_K, i_* (\pi_1 \partial X_K))$
The peripheral group system with a preferred meridian $(\pi_1 X_K, i_* (\pi_1 \partial X_K),m)$
The knot quandle $Q(K)= \pi_0 \mathrm{hofib}(\partial X_K \hookrightarrow X_K)$

(1) is a truly complete knot invariant (Burde-Zieschang Theorem 3.15), whereas if it comes to (4), two oriented knots $K,K'$ have isomorphic knot quandles if and only if $K'=K$ or $K'=rmK$ the reverse of the mirror image of $K$ (this is due to  Matveev's theorem which states that an isomorphism of the knot quandles must be induced by a homeomorphism of pairs that preserve the orientation of the normal bundle of the knot).
What about (2) and (3)? For instance I suspect that (2) determines the isotopy class of the knot only up to orientation and/or mirror image, because the Waldhausen theorem does not ensure a orientation-preserving homeomorphism between the knot exteriors (and this is needed for the characterisation of the unoriented isotopy class provided by the Gordon-Luecke theorem.

If $\pi_1X_K=\mathbb Z$ then $K$ is the unknot. Assume this is not the case, then the property $P$ conjecture (solved) tells you $m$ (up to sign) is distinguished in the peripheral subgroup. Of course, by abelization, $\ell$ (up to sign) is also distinguished in the peripheral system, characterized by the fact that $\ell$ is primitive and $[\ell]=0\in H_1(X_K)$.
Therefore, (2) determines $K$ up to orientation and/or mirror. The extra structure in (3) further picks out $m$ from $\pm m$, so (3) determines $K$ up to $K\sim rmK$.
